# How do you know where a csv file is stored once you write a DataFrame onto disk?

Tags: python, pandas

```
     import pandas as pd
     hand_1=pd.DataFrame({
    'Tables of 5':[5,10,15,20,25],
    'Tables of 6':[6,12,18,24,30]})

     hand_1.to_csv('Tables.csv')`
```

How do i find out where Tables.csv is stored?

Is this where python stores csv files by default and can this be changed?

Comment: `hand_1.to_csv('Tables.csv')` will save the file to current working dir, which can be seen by `os.getcwd()`

Comment: Usually in the working directory of your Python script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be saved in your current working directory. If you would like to learn it, you can use the following code:

```
import os
current_directory = os.getcwd()
```

You can give a full path instead of `tables.csv` to store in another directory.